# Enable Sonos microphone via API

Tags: sonos

Is there any way to enable/disable the microphone on Sonos One (2. Gen) via API calls? E.g. on the [openhab binding for sonos](https://www.openhab.org/addons/bindings/sonos/) I can track the state of the microphone, but can't change it. However when adding any voice assistant the microphone is turned on automatically at the Sonos One so it is possible via software, right?

Answer (score 0):

Microphone access is very limited indeed due to privacy concerns. I am not aware of any way of accessing it directly.